# how to charge two 18650 3.7v batteries?

Tags: voltage, batteries, voltage-regulator, battery-charging

i have two 18650 batteries of this [type](https://www.123accu.nl/123accu-18650-batterij-1-stuk-3-7V-2600mAh-i26531.html) (but with one 1500mAh and one 2000mAh)
and i need to charge them with two (or more if needed) 6v 1A solar panels.
I was looking around and found [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/TP5100-2-cells-single-Lithium-ion-Battery-Charger-Module-2A-18650-Charging-PCB/181687643612?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131003132420%26meid%3D6b7158e5260447909c709ee611179609%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D171753145841)  but this one is 4.2v instead of 3.7, and i'm reading mixed things about if this would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4.2V voltage at 100% charge is good for 3.7 Li ion battery, but they must be the same type, age, same batch. You can't pick up batteries whatever comes in yopur hand.

Comment: hey marko :) thanks for answering, would the charger i link be alright to charge two of the same type batteries, and would i need to take them out in a certain time so they dont overcharge?

Comment: thanks for answering marko :). could the charger i linked charge two identical 18650 batteries without any problems?